# Вывести записи определенного уровня wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Есть посты такой структуры:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос: как вывести записи только 3-го уровня, если мы находимся на странице 1-го уровня. Если бы было всего 2 уровня, я бы получал id текущей страницы и с args array добавлял бы `'post_parent' => $id_текущей_страницы`, и выводились бы все дочерние записи.

Answer (score 2):

В цикле для полученных дочерних постов второго уровня получайте их id и действуйте аналогичным образом

**Обновление:**
Модификация кода, обсуждаемого в комментариях

```
$childrens = get_children($args, $output);
$children_ids = array();
if ($childrens) {    
    foreach ($childrens as $children) {
        array_push($children_ids, $children->ID);
    }
}
```

Далее `'post_parent__in' => $children_ids`

Comment: Да, в принципе так и делаю. Получаю id дочерних постов:
`$childrens = get_children( $args, $output );
        if( $childrens ){
        foreach( $childrens as $children ){
        $tmp = $tmp . $children->ID .  ",";
        }
        }`
Но возникает проблема. Надо в массив передать полученные id в таком виде: `'post_parent__in' => array(94,84)`, а перменная `$tmp` выводит 94,84,. ,т.е. с лишней запятой на конце. Как от нее избавиться, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: добавляйте значения в массив функцией `array_push()`. Обновила ответ, дополнив примером кода

Comment: спасибо, выручили)